# It's time for a clock challenge!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, date

I'd like you to build me a clock that displays time in this format:

```
18 ----------
19 --------------------------------------------------
```

This displays '18:10'. The current hour and the next hour are shown at the front of the line, followed by a space and a number of dashes: on the first line the number of minutes that have passed in this hour, and the second line shows how many more minutes to go in this hour.

## To clarify

- The clock should display the system's time. If fetching the time from another source is more convenient, that's fine too. It *may not* be supplied as input.
- At `18:00`, the top line is just `18` (Trailing spaces allowed but not required)
- At `18:59`, the bottom line is `19 -`
- The hours < 10 are either pre-padded with a `0` (`01 -----`) or right-aligned ( `1 -----`). A left-aligned single digit is not allowed, not even if the dashes start at the right place (`1  -----` is invalid).
- The clock should display the hours in a 24h-format.
- Although it's called the 24h format, there is not actually a `24` on it. During the 23rd hour, the second line starts with `00` or  `0`.
- The display needs to be updated at least once a minute, but that doesn't have to happen at exactly `00` seconds. You may update more frequently / continuously if that is more convenient, but the result must of course still be legible - not one smear all over the screen.

## Input

None.

## Output

- As described above. Trailing spaces to pad the clock to 60-ish positions is allowed on both lines, a trailing newline is also allowed.
- The screen needs to be cleared when displaying the next minute: either with a clear-screen command or by adding no less than 30 newlines.

## Additional rules

- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: may we have two spaces between the number and the dashes?

Comment: @Adám I think not, see the last example in "To clarify" bullet #4. But this may not address your question, which is more general.

Comment: "updated once a minute" -- Can it be updated more often?

Comment: @smls Yes, you may update as often as you like. I'll change the specs to 'at least once a minute'.

Comment: @Adám No, only one space between the numbers and he dashes.

Comment: Does it have to print immediately or can it print after a minute?

Comment: Just to clarify, is it okay for numbers less than 10 to be outputted like this `1 -----` **without** a leading space?

Comment: @KritixiLithos That would break alignment with two-digit hours (9, 10 or 23, 00), so no, not allowed.

Comment: Can I have a leading space on all lines (and two leading spaces for single digits)? It would save about a gajillion bytes in QBasic.

Comment: Actually, it may not be a gajillion--looks like `PRINT USING` can be used to avoid the leading space for positive numbers. TIL. But thanks. :)

Comment: After 23, is the next hour 24 or 0?

Comment: @KritixiLithos It's 0.

Comment: @steenbergh: You might want to clarify that in the question, since practically every submission has 24.

Comment: @kundor Added your suggestion.

Comment: for languages with no datetime functions, can we take current time as input?

Comment: @Razetime sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 41 bytes

*Thanks to @Kundor for noticing a mistake, now corrected*

```
`XxFT"4&Z'@+24\OH&YAO'-'60@*5&Z'-|Y"hhD]T
```

Try it at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=%60XxFT%224%26Z%27%40%2B24%5COH%26YAO%27-%2760%40%2a5%26Z%27-%7CY%22hhD%5DT&inputs=&version=19.7.1) But note that the program is killed after 30 seconds, so it's difficult to catch any changes in the output.

#### How it works

```
`           % Do...while
  Xx        %   Clear screen
  FT        %   Push [0 1]
  "         %   For each k in [0 1]
    4&Z'    %     Push current hour
    @+      %     Add k
    24\     %     Modulo 24. This transforms 24 into 0
    OH&YA   %     Convert to base-10 string with 2 digits
    O       %     Push 0. Concatenating with chars will convert this to char,
            %     and char(0) will be displayed as a space
    '-'     %     Push '-'
    60@*    %     Push 60*k
    5&Z'    %     Push current minute
    -|      %     Absolute difference. This gives current minute for k==0,
            %     or 60 minus that for k==1
    Y"      %     Repeat '-' that many times
    hh      %     Concatenate the top three elements into a string
    D      %      Display
  ]         %   End
  T         %   Push true
            % End (implicit). Since the top of the stack contains true, this
            % gives an infinite loop
```

Comment: Could be me, but at the second iteration, only the top line is printed...

Comment: @steenbergh It works for me with minutes and seconds instead of hours and minutes, so the changes are easily seen: https://matl.suever.net/?code=%60XxFT"5%26Z%27%40%2BOH%26YAO%27-%2760%40%2a6%26Z%27-%7CkY"hhD%5DT&inputs=&version=19.7.1

Comment: Yep, works. - in fact, might be cool to have this as lines 3 and 4 of my own clock.

Comment: @steenbergh: you accepted this answer, but it's not valid—it shows the hour after 23 as 24. I believe the shortest correct answer is the Ruby one by Value Ink.

Comment: @kundor Thanks for noticing. Corrected at the cost of 3 bytes

Answer (score 11):

## TI-Basic, 94 bytes

```
" 
Repeat 99<length(Ans
Ans+"-
End
Ans→Str1
Repeat 0
getTime
ClrDraw
Ans{Ans(1)≠24,1,1
Text(0,0,Ans(1),sub(Str1,1,1+Ans(2
Text(6,0,Ans(1)+1,sub(Str1,1,61-Ans(2
End
```

Relatively straightforward. That's a string with one space at the beginning. The hours are right-aligned. This only works on TI-84+ calculators since the TI-83 does not have an internal clock.

Edit: Thanks @kundor for noticing that I didn't close the last loop. Fixed now (+2 bytes).

Edit #2: First hour should be zero, not twenty-four. Corrected at a cost of +14 bytes.

Comment: Every command count as one byte ?

Comment: @Sygmei Most tokens are one byte, yes. However, tokens such as `Str1`, `getTime`, and `sub(` are two bytes each. You can learn more at http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/tokens

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to an emulator, would you?

Comment: I would recommend https://www.cemetech.net/projects/jstified/ but do remember that it's morally wrong to use a ROM from the internet with this emulator unless you own that type of calculator yourself.

Comment: I would never, ever use this ROM to actually calculate anything! Perish the thought.

Comment: Don't be scared to click the link, because the emulator is legit and asks you to upload your own ROM before it will work. TI used to have them freely available but they're not any more. If you can find a TI-84 from a friend, that would be the best option.

Comment: At least in wabbitemu on my phone, this doesn't seem to update unless I add `End` at the end of the program, in which case it blinks constantly.

Comment: Hey @kundor, it was my fault that I didn't add the `End` statement -- thanks for the catch. But, the blinking may be a result of the emulator. If you want, clearing the `ClrDraw` command may give you nicer results on your emulator. It's required for the challenge, though.

Answer (score 9):

### Batch, 197 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ah=100+%time:~0,2%,m=1%time:~3,2%
cls
call:l
set/ah=(h-3)%%24+100,m=260-m
call:l
timeout/t>nul 60
%0
:l
set s=%h:~1% 
for /l %%i in (101,1,%m%)do call set s=%%s%%-
echo %s%
```

Note: 10th line has a trailing space. For me, `%time%` formats hours with a leading space but minutes with a leading zero. I decided a leading zero was an easier output format, since all I have to do for that is to add 100 hours and remove the first digit. Minutes are trickier as `08` or `09` will cause octal parse errors, so I prefix a `1` effectively adding 100 minutes, adjusting for this by offsetting the loop appropriately, which is a byte shorter than subtracting the 100.

Answer (score 7):

### Python 3.6, <s>110</s> <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```python
from time import*
while[sleep(9)]:h,m=localtime()[3:5];print('\n'*50+'%2d '%h+'-'*m+f'\n{-~h%24:2} '+'-'*(60-m))
```

This uses the new f-string formatting to save one byte (`f'\n{h+1:2} '` vs `'\n%2d '%(h+1)`.) You can change `[sleep(9)]` to  `1` to save 8 bytes, but then it just spams the screen.

Saved one byte changing `while 1:...;sleep 60` to `while[sleep(60)]:...`, thanks to TuukkaX.

I had to use 5 more bytes to get the next hour displayed after 23 to be 0, instead of 24, as OP just commented. :-(

Recovered one byte by only sleeping 9 seconds instead of 60.

Saved two bytes using a bit-fiddling to shorten `(h+1)%24`, borrowed from [Value Ink's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107148/18314).

Comment: Could you please explain why you've put square brackets around the if condition? Wouldn't just having the space between while and sleep be 1 byte, as opposed to the 2 on either side? EDIT: Never mind, it's to make it truthy. Fair enough.

Comment: @shadow: `sleep` returns `None`, which is falsy.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén: `sleep` is also in the `time` module, so importing * is better.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>98</s> <s>95</s> 91 bytes

Updates every 5 seconds. Only works in Unix-style terminals.

```
loop{t=Time.now;puts`clear`+"%02d %s
%02d "%[h=t.hour,?-*m=t.min,-~h%24]+?-*(60-m);sleep 5}
```

Windows command prompt version, <s>95</s> 92 bytes:

```
loop{t=Time.now;puts"\e[H\e[2J%02d %s
%02d "%[h=t.hour,?-*m=t.min,-~h%24]+?-*(60-m);sleep 5}
```

Comment: Can you use backticks instead of system? `\`cls\`` vs `system'cls'`

Comment: It seems not, but you can use `h=t.hour` and then use `h` instead of the second `t.hour`, which saves 3 bytes.

Comment: @IMP1 indeed, backticks don't work for `cls`. Thanks for your other suggestion, though!

Comment: @IMP1 as it turns out, `puts\`clear\`` is the way to go if you use Unix terminals. It just doesn't work with the Windows command prompt `cls`.

Comment: For windows, you can `puts"\e[H\e[2J"` to clear the console, which I think shaves four bytes.
It would make your first line read `loop{t=Time.now;puts"\e[H\e[2J%02d %s`

Comment: @IMP1 thanks! Although, it only saved 3 bytes AFAIK

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 113 bytes

```perl6
loop {$_=DateTime.now;.put for |('' xx 30),|([\+](.hour,1)».fmt('%2s')Z('-' Xx[\-](.minute,60)».abs));sleep 60}
```

[Try it once](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#FcrLCoJAFADQX7lQMTOkgxW4SNr1AS1aRBphccWBecg8aEL9snb9mNnmrM7JGiUccqHphnHfot5Dj1H4ERYg0YPwYIMGo@V75omTNKaDfnk/HGuPZ6GQa/MqeBc8NMbCQAmBGGGXsWSgZbW@Ud6aYJMN@354ozwlq60j7EpJSuASyyqdhxI6eEzy7J/qh2OscBKxgzwbp@kH) with a one second timeout.

[Or try an altered version](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#hZDBSsQwEIbvfYofdiUJdktXYQ8uvfkIHsRdWdLt1BabpDSpLbg@mTdfrKYtgrKKA7n8M/PN/2dYHpDgVjq6KxVF2nRbfKsF0obkM0oH0/qXwxWEypga1qAjHKX2TWo8IAgm/TUIxr3lIfmDusDRKEXaUTZBPcgV0o03RtqxkPqJkJLriL7gpdF25Ea1X8hNgxNnDH2P61iEJ77bXz7yqDBtE67Fx3uUK8fZxZVl4oGzFcN9v9uv/IQqdeso3MTjkEytENvZra2IamxinNU/br00WlKmIbzIqqXJpv/UKEHl8zccN/NVvhYQE1BmGSRm9QdvSm5/jf42DJ8) that outputs the result of running for several hours.

### Expanded:

```perl6
loop {                  # keep repeating forever

  $_ = DateTime.now;    # assign an object representing the current time

    .put                # print with trailing newline
                        # ( adds a space between numbers and dashes )

  for                   # for each of the following

    |(                  # make it a slip so that it is all part of one list

      '' xx 30          # 30 empty strings (30 empty lines)
    ),

    |(

        [\+](           # triangle produce
          .hour,        # the hour
          1             # the hour plus one

        )».fmt( '%2s' ) # both formatted to two element string ( space padded )

      Z                 # zipped with

        (
            '-'         # a dash

          Xx            # cross (X) using string repeat (x) operator

            [\-](       # triangle produce
              .minute,  # the minute
              60        # the minute minus 60

            )».abs      # absolute value of both
        )
    );

  sleep 60              # wait until the next minute
}
```

Comment: What operators does the 'triangle produce' support? In `[\+]` it adds and in `[\-]` it seems to subtract. Does this work with multiplication and such?

Comment: @TuukkaX It should work with almost all infix operators. It is basically the same as `[+] LIST` which is reduce, except it gives you the intermediate values. See the docs page for [produce](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/produce)

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8, <strike>313</strike> <strike>300</strike> 299 bytes

```
import java.time.*;()->{for(int c=0,h=LocalDateTime.now().getHour(),m=LocalDateTime.now().getMinute(),i;;)if(c>30){c=0;String l="",u,d;for(i=0;i++<60;)l+="-";u=l.substring(0,m);d=l.substring(m);System.out.println((h<10?"0":"")+h+" "+u+"\n"+(h<9?"0":"")+(h+1)+" "+d);}else{c++;System.out.println();}}
```

This only updates every 30 iterations of the while loop.  The other 29 iterations just print new lines.

**Updated**

Saved <strike>13</strike> 14 bytes due to Kevin Cruijssen's help! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! First of all, only programs/functions are allowed, and your current code is a snippet. You'll have to surround it with a method (i.e. `void f(){...}` and need to add the imports it required (in your case `import java.time.*;`). That being said, your code can be golfed at multiple places to lower it to **311 bytes** (even with the added method-declaration and import). (Since it's too long for this comment, I've placed it in the next comment.. xD)

Comment: `import java.time.*;void f(){for(int c=0,h=LocalDateTime.now().getHour(),m=LocalDateTime.now().getMinute(),i;;)if(c>99){c=0;String l="",u,d;for(i=0;i++<61;)l+="-";u=l.substring(0,m);d=l.substring(m);System.out.println((h<10?"0":"")+h+" "+u+"\n"+(h<9?"0":"")+(h+1)+" "+d);}else{c++;System.out.println();}}` (**303 bytes**) I recommend reading [Tips for Golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages). Enjoy your stay.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I updated my answer and was able to save 3 more bytes by using lambda notation.  Also I changed a few pieces to the code you provided, as well, to meet the specifications (e.g. `for(i=0;i++<60` instead of 61 and `(h<10?` instead of 9.  Thanks for informing me about method declaration and some golfing tips!

Comment: Ah, the 61 instead of 60 was indeed my mistake. I thought I had written it as `for(i=0;++i<61` instead of `for(i=0;i++<61` (in this second case it should indeed be 60, and even though it's the same amount of bytes, it's probably more obvious/readable). The `h<9` in my code is correct, though. You had `h+1<10` before and I simply changed this to `h<9` by removing 1 on both sides. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ha I didn't pick up on that! `h<9`.  I will edit it to save 1 more byte.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

## QBasic, <s>120</s> <s>127</s> 121 bytes

<s>Don't run this for very long or your laptop will catch fire.</s> Now 99.several9s% more CPU-efficient.

```
CLS
m=TIMER\60
h=m\60
m=m MOD 60
FOR i=1TO 2
?USING"## ";h MOD 24;
FOR j=1TO m
?"-";
NEXT
?
h=h+1
m=60-m
NEXT
SLEEP 1
RUN
```

#### Ungolfed and explanation

```
DO
    CLS
    totalMinutes = TIMER \ 60
    hour = totalMinutes \ 60
    minute = totalMinutes MOD 60

    FOR row = 1 TO 2
        PRINT USING "## "; hour MOD 24;
        FOR j = 1 TO minute
            PRINT "-";
        NEXT j
        PRINT

        hour = hour + 1
        minute = 60 - minute
    NEXT row

    SLEEP 1
LOOP
```

We start by clearing the screen, then get the current hours and minutes from `TIMER`, which returns the number of seconds since midnight.

This is the first time I've tried `PRINT USING`, so I was delighted to discover that it doesn't suffer from the usual QBasic quirk that positive numbers are printed with a leading space. `##` as the format specifier ensures that single-digit numbers are right-aligned and padded with a space, as required. We have to use a loop for the hyphens, unfortunately, since QBasic does not have a string repetition function. (If I'm mistaken, please let me know!)

All the `PRINT` statements end with `;` to suppress the newline; but after the hyphens, we need a newline; thus, the solitary `?` after the inner `FOR` loop.

The `SLEEP 1` is now necessary. Without it, the screen gets cleared so quickly after printing that it's just a flickering mess. (I used `LOCATE 1` instead of `CLS` at first for that reason, until I realized that `CLS` with `SLEEP` is shorter anyway.) `RUN` restarts the program from the top--the shortest way to get an infinite loop.

Comment: How does this handle the last hour of the day? Top line reads 23, but what;'s the hour on the bottom line?

Comment: I'm using the Note7 and thinking of running this program for the foreseeable future in place of my status bar clock. Is that a good idea?

Comment: @steenbergh Whoops, fixed. It would be helpful for you to mention that edge case in the question.

Comment: @DLosc Nah, I'm just joking :)). But yeah, smart!!

Comment: @DLosc I see you're still just adding 1 to the hour for line 2. Again, I don't see how does this handles 23/00?

Comment: @steenbergh He prints h MOD 24, if initially h=23 then the next loop cycle its 24 and gets modded to 0. But I'm curious if it works as well. The CLS clears the first line so there are never both printed lines on the screen, right?

Comment: @Jens it works fine -- the `CLS` is only called when the main loop (defined by `RUN`) loops, so both lines are printed, then there's the `SLEEP 1`, then the CLS etc.

Comment: In the line `FOR j=1TO m` what happens if m is 0? Does it skip or result in an endless loop?  Online interpreters seem to go into an endless loop.

Comment: @styletron It works as expected (skips the loop) in [QB64](http://qb64.net) and on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack). Other emulators I've tried (such as repl.it) are *very* incomplete, so I'm not surprised to hear that they're buggy.

Answer (score 4):

### C, <s>176</s> <s>162</s> <s>161</s> <s>160</s> 156 bytes

This is a **gross** abuse of pointers but compiles and runs as specified.  Be sure to compile without optimization otherwise you are likely to hit a segfault.

```
main(){int*localtime(),b[9],*t;memset(b,45,60);for(;;)time(&t),t=localtime(&t),usleep(printf("\e[2J%.2d %.*s\n%.2d %.*s\n",t[2],t[1],b,t[2]+1,60-t[1],b));}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
#import<time.h>
main()
{
 int *t,b[60];
 memset(b,45,60);
 for(;;) {
  time(&t);
  t=localtime(&t);
  usleep(printf("\e[2J%.2d %.*s\n%.2d %.*s\n",t[2],t[1],b,t[2]+1,60-t[1],b));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>131</s> <s>129</s> 127 bytes

```
from time import*
while[sleep(9)]:exec(strftime("a='%H';b=int('%M')"));print "\n"*30+a+" "+"-"*b+"\n"+`int(a)+1`+" "+"-"*(60-b)
```

saved a byte thanks to @TuukkaX

Comment: You don't need the newline and space after the `while 1:`

Comment: I started your code @19:55. At 20:01, I see `19 - \n
20 -----------------------------------------------------------`. The hours aren't updating...

Comment: @steenbergh I tried it myself by setting the clock manually and it works for me.

Comment: @ovs aren't clock challenges fun :-). Anyway, probably something with repl.it then...

Comment: *head-desk* The Repl.it server is one hour behind to my local time... And it even says so at the very top of the console. I'll see myself out, thanks...

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 162 bytes

Updates once per second

```js
setInterval(c=>{c.clear(d=new Date,m=d.getMinutes(),h=d.getHours(),H=_=>`0${h++}`.slice(-2)),c.log(H()+` ${'-'.repeat(m)}
${H()} `+'-'.repeat(60-m))},1e3,console)
```

Comment: You can save quite a few bytes by restructuring the code so it is only one statement (it's possible to call `console.clear()` inside the `console.log` argument) and assigning in unused parentheses as much as possible. Version for 154B: `setInterval(c=>c.log(H(h,c.clear(d=new Date))+\` ${'-'.repeat(m)}
${H(h+1)} \`+'-'.repeat(60-m)),1e3,console,m=d.getMinutes(h=d.getHours(H=$=>$<9?'0'+$:$)))`.

Comment: You can save a bunch of byte by putting the hours and minutes into a single function `m=>\`0${h++} \.slice(-3)+'-'.repeat(m)`.

Answer (score 3):

### C <s>251</s> <s>267</s> 251 bytes

```
 #include<time.h>f(){time_t t;struct tm *t1;h,m,i;while(1){time(&t);t1=localtime(&t);h=t1->tm_hour;m=t1->tm_min;printf("%d ",h);for(i=1;i<=m;i++)printf("-");puts("");printf("%d ",h+1);for(i=0;i<=59-m;i++)printf("-");puts("");sleep(1);system("clear");}}
```

Ungolfed version

```
#include<time.h>
void f()
{
 time_t t;
 struct tm *t1;
 int h,m,i;

 while(1)
 {
  time(&t);     
  t1=localtime(&t);
  h=t1->tm_hour;
  m=t1->tm_min;

  printf("%d ",h);
  for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
   printf("-");

  puts("");
  printf("%d ",h+1);

  for(i=0;i<=59-m;i++)
   printf("-");

  puts("");    

  sleep(1);
  system("clear");    
 }
}
```

Gets the work done! Can definitely be shortened in some way.
Assume `unistd.h` file is included.

@Neil Thanks for the info.

@Seth Thanks, for saving 8 bytes.

Comment: IIRC you have to _include_ everything necessary to get the code to compile (in this case, the definitions of `time_t` and `struct tm`) in your byte count.

Comment: Instead of `printf("\n");` you can use `puts("");`

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>104</s> 105 bytes

```php
<? for(;;sleep(6))printf("%'
99s%2d %'-".($m=date(i))."s
%2d %'-".(60-$m).s,"",$h=date(H),"",++$h%24,"");
```

showcase for `printf`´s custom padding characters:
`"%'-Ns"`=left pad string with `-` to `N` characters.

will print 99 newlines (every 6 seconds) instead of clearing the screen.

First newline must be a single character. So, on Windows, it must be replaced with `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

First time golfing...

## Powershell, 116 bytes (was 122)

```
while($d=date){$f="{0:D2}";$h=$d.Hour;$m=$d.Minute;cls;"$($f-f$h)$("-"*$m)`n$($f-f(++$h%24))$("-"*(60-$m))";Sleep 9}
```

Edit: From @AdmBorkBork's advice, changed Get-Date to date, and Clear to cls, for a saving of 6 bytes.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, good answer

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! A couple easy golfs -- you can use `cls` instead of `clear` and (so long as you're on Windows) `date` instead of `get-date`. I'm also sure there's some easier way to output the formatting -- I'm playing with it and I'll let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: Nice. Try this: 108 bytes `while($d=date){cls;"{0,2} {2}``n{1,2} {3}"-f($h=$d.Hour),(++$h%24),('-'*($m=$d.Minute)),('-'*(60-$m));Sleep 9}`. Use LF line break in your editor instead ``n`

Answer (score 2):

## GameMaker Language, 134 bytes

```
s=" "while 1{s+="-"a=current_hour b=current_minute draw_text(0,0,string(a)+string_copy(s,1,b+1)+"#"+string(a+1)+string_copy(s,0,61-b)}
```

In the settings, you must be ignoring non-fatal errors in order for this to work. Also, in GML, `#` is equivalent to `\n` in most languages.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/) (aka Perl 6), 104 bytes

```
DateTime.now.&{"\ec{.hour.fmt: '%2s'} {'-'x.minute}\n{(.hour+1).fmt: '%2s'} {'-'x 60-.minute}"}.say xx*
```

Needs to be run on a [ANSI compatible terminal](https://graphcomp.com/info/specs/ansi_col.html) so that the control sequence for resetting the terminal works.

Pretty basic (because the more obfuscated approaches I tried turned out longer):

- `DateTime.now.&{"  "}.say xx*`: Transform the current time into a string (see below) and say it, and repeat all of that an infinite number of times. The string is built like this:
- `\ec`: ANSI control code `<ESC>c` for resetting the terminal, which clears the screen.
- `{.hour.fmt: '%2s'}`: hour, right-aligned to 2 columns
- : space
- `{'-'x.minute}`: dash repeated times the minute
- `\n`: newline
- `{(.hour+1).fmt: '%2s'}`: next hour, right-aligned to 2 columns
- : space
- `{'-'x 60-.minute}`: dash repeated times 60 minus the minute

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>112</s> 120 bytes

```
for(;;sleep(9))echo($s=str_pad)($h=date(H),99,"\n",0).$s(" ",1+$m=date(i),"-")."\n".$s(++$h%24,2,0,0).$s(" ",61-$m,"-");
```

As there's no way to clear the screen (that I can find) I had to go with a pile of newlines. Also the question being updated to "at least" once a minute saves a byte with `9` instead of `60`.

edit: @Titus noticed a bug in the padding of the second hour. Fixing it cost 8 bytes.

Comment: This displays warning text on stdout along with the correct output: `Notice: Use of undefined constant str_pad - assumed 'str_pad' in C:\wamp64\www\my-site\a.php on line 2 - Notice: Use of undefined constant H - assumed 'H' in C:\wamp64\www\my-site\a.php on line 2 - Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\wamp64\www\my-site\a.php on line 2`. Anything on Meta about that?

Comment: @steenbergh That´s a notice; it will not be displayed if you use default values (command line parameter `-n` or `error_reporting(22519);`

Comment: hours must be padded to length 2

Comment: Good point, the `H` setting for date goes from 00-23, but I forgot about it for the second hour.

Comment: Save two bytes with physical linebreaks.

Comment: ... and 7 more with this: Remove `1+` and replace everything from `."\n"` to the end with `$p(date("-\ns ",++$h%24),65-$i,"-");`.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3.5, <s>127</s> 120 <s>117</s> bytes

```python
from time import*
while[sleep(9)]:h,m=localtime()[3:5];print('\n'*88,*['%2d '%x+'-'*y+'\n'for x,y in[(h,m),(h+1,60-m)]])
```

Comment: Can you not just `print('\n'*50)` instead  of `os.system('cls')` so it works on both *nix and Windows? Would save a couple of bytes as you can lose the `os` import and OP says that this is allowed.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read it properly then. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Just for info, most people tend to use <s></s> around their old byte count and then put the new byte count after it because it is interesting to see the progress as an answer is improved :-) Must try 3.5 some time. I'm still working with Python 2.

Comment: @ElPedro Yea I forgot to do it. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>115</s> 113 bytes

<sub>saved a couple of bytes thanks to @kundor and @Phlarx</sub>

```
import time
while 1:h,m=time.localtime()[3:5];print("\x1b[0;H{:02} {}\n{:02} {} ".format(h,"-"*m,h+1,"-"*(60-m)))
```

Comment: At least on my system, this doesn't erase underlying characters, so that the number of dashes on the second line doesn't go down as time passes. Also: you can save three bytes by putting your while loop on one line, and two bytes by changing the `:02` formats to just `:2`.

Comment: You can fix the issue described by @kundor in 1 byte by adding a space after the corresponding {}.

Comment: @kundor fixed! Thanks. I kept the `:02` format to right-pad one digit hours with zeroes.

Comment: @kundor *left-pad one digit hours with zeroes.

Comment: @dfernan: Well, `:2` left-pads with spaces, which the challenge says is OK.

Answer (score 2):

### AWK, 190 bytes

```
#!/bin/awk -f
func p(x,y,c){printf("%2s ",x)
for(j=0;j<y;j++)printf(c)
print}BEGIN{for(;;){split(strftime("%H %M"),t)
m=t[2]
if(o!=m){p(a,30,"\n")
p(t[1],m,"-")
p((t[1]+1)%24,60-m,"-")}o=m}}
```

Since `AWK` doesn't have a built-in `sleep` function, I simply have it continually check the clock to see if the minute has changed yet. The key thing is that it works... right? :)

Answer (score 2):

## BASH, <strike>165</strike> <strike>141</strike> 155 bytes

```
while :
do
clear
m=`date +%-M`
a=`printf %${m}s`
b=`printf %$((60-m))s`
h=`date +%H`
echo $h ${a// /-}
printf "%02d %s" $((10#$h+1)) ${b// /-}
sleep 9
done
```

Comment: I could save another 8 bytes removing the sleep, but I'm not comfortable with an indefinite while loop running on my computer without a sleep ;-)

Comment: Some optimizations: move `sleep 9` to the condition of the while loop; remove the `-` in front of M in the format string on line 4. You also don't need to use $ in front of variable names in arithmetic expressions, so `$((60-$m))` can be `$((60-m))`

Comment: I'm not sure whether your math on line 9 is accurate: `h=23; echo $((10#$h+1))` prints 24 for me.

Comment: Whats wrong with 24?

Comment: I need the -M because $((60-08)) gives an error.

Comment: If I put sleep in the condition, which saves me 2 bytes, I would need to wait 9 seconds for the clock to appear ...

$((60-m)) saves me 1 byte though. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

### C# *Interactive* (138 Bytes)

```
while(true){var d=DateTime.Now;Console.WriteLine($"{d.Hour:00} {new string('-',d.Minute)}\n{d.Hour+1:00} {new string('-',60-d.Minute)}");}
```

Comment: Can you golf this down by 1) naming the date var `d` instead of `dt`? and 2) use `sleep(1e3)` or `999` instead of `1000`?

Comment: @steenbergh see update

Comment: A few things... This is just a snippet not a method or program (not sure if it's valid in C# Interactive though), it is essentially a golfed version of my code, and if it is should have been commented as improvements not a separate solution (though this is speculation) and there are lots of small improvements you can make here, and do you even need the sleep?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I specifically put C# *Interactive* because this works in the interactive console ONLY. This would not work as a standard C# program.

Comment: Also note that this won't work when the hour is 23 and when the minute is 0

Comment: Golfing tips: `true`=>`1>0`, `WriteLine`=>`Write`, set `d.Hour` and `d.Minute` to variables etc... Also I don't know C# Interactive but you probably have to include `using System;` into the byte count

Comment: @TheLethalCoder if you have VS2015+ you can try this out in interactive yourself...it comes shipped with VS, but thanks for the tips

Comment: Also this solution is invalid (assuming consecutive calls to `Console.WriteLine` don't clear the console in interactive) as each call is placed on top of the other and not clearing the console as required

Answer (score 2):

## Bash (3 and 4): 90 bytes

```
d=(`sed s/./-/g<$0`);let `date +h=%H,m=%M`;echo $h ${d:0:m}'
'$[++h%24] ${d:m}
sleep 5
$0
```

Due to the use of `$0`, this script must be put into a file, not pasted into an interactive bash shell.

The first command sets `$d` to 60 hyphens; it relies on the fact that the first line of this script is 60 characters long. This is three characters shorter than the next best thing I could come up with:

```
d=`printf %060d|tr 0 -`
```

If you don't want this to run your box out of PIDs or memory eventually, you can add `eval` to the beginning of the last line, which would make this 95 bytes.

Comment: Gives me the error `let: h=09: value too great for base (error token is "09")`. Problem is that leading zeros are interpreted as octal constants, so 09 is invalid.

Comment: Hrm, that means my script is broken in several ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 154 bytes

```
S+N:-get_time(A),format_time(atom(O),S,A),atom_number(O,N).
:-repeat,"%H"+H,"%M"+M,format("~t~d~2+ ~|~45t~*+
~|~t~d~2+ ~|~45t~*+
",[H,H,M,M]),\+sleep(60).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P1jbz0o3PbUkviQzN1XDUVMnLb8oNxHKTSzJz9Xw19QJ1gFKgDjxeaW5SalFGv46fpp6XFa6RakFqYklOkqqHkraHkDKV0nbF2qChlJdSV1KnZG2Ql1NnYlpSZ2WNheQhSGmpBPtoeOh46vjG6upE6NdnJOaWqBhZqCp9/8/AA)

Welp, what a mess.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gura](https://github.com/gura-lang/gura), 138 bytes

```
k(a,b)={if(a<10){a="0"+a;}println(a," ","-"*b)};repeat{t=datetime.now();k(t.hour,t.min);k(t.hour+1,60-t.min);os.sleep(60);print("\n"*30);}
```

Pretty short and straightforward :)

Comment: Wow ... That's fast. Any tips on running Gura? Just downloaded the binaries, but running `Gura.exe` and pasting in this code gives me a syntax error `symbol k is not defined`.

Comment: Forgot a semicolon ! You can try to run it again :)

Comment: Does this update every minute? The console seems to run this code just once...

Comment: Woops, did not saw that part, should be working now !

Comment: When it updates, it should either clear the screen or add 30 newlines. Man, I'm on your case...

Comment: I rushed, I should have been more attentive :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, haven't done a code golf in a while, so here goes my sad attempt :)

## Unix Korn Shell: <s>177</s> <s>171</s> 170 bytes

```
while :
do
clear
h=`date +%H`
m=`date +%M`
d=-----
d=$d$d$d$d
d=$d$d$d
a=`echo $d|cut -b-$m`
let m=60-$m
b=`echo $d|cut -b-$m`
let i=h+1
echo "$h $a\n$i $b"
sleep 9
done
```

Comment: spliced the 2 echos into 1, saved a few bytes ... (sleep 9 instead of sleep 10 saves 1 byte :P )  lol

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, <s>204</s> <s>200</s> <s>198</s> 197 bytes

*5 bytes saved thanks to @L. Serné by using smarter ternaries*

```processing
void draw(){int i;String s=((i=hour())>9?i:" "+i)+" ";for(i=0;i<minute();i++)s+="-";s+="\n"+((i=hour()+1)>9?i>23?" 0":i:" "+i)+" ";for(i=0;i<60-minute();i++)s+="-";print(s);for(;i++<99;)println();}
```

This outputs 30+ newlines for each update (which takes place when the frame gets updated)

#### Ungolfed

```processing
void draw(){
  int i;
  String s=((i=hour())>9?i:" "+i)+" ";
  for(i=0;i<minute();i++)
    s+="-";
  s+="\n"+((i=hour()+1)>9?i>23?" 0":i:" "+i)+" ";
  for(i=0;i<60-minute();i++)
    s+="-";print(s);
  for(;i++<99;)
    println();
}
```

Comment: Changing `((i=hour())<10?" ":"")+i` into `((i=hour())>9?i:" "+i)` would save 2B twice... Good luck with further golfing!

Comment: @L.Serne thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Another improvement that might work: `((i=hour()+1)>24?i=0:i)>9` becomes `(i=hour()+1)>9`, since `hour` outputs a number in the range 0-23, and even with 1 added to that, it'll never be greater than 24. Also, you should move the increment of `i` inside the condition in the `for` loop like you did in the very last loop. Should save 13B in total.

Comment: @L.Serné For the first point, I still have to include the ternary because 23+1 in a 24-hour clock becomes 0 (or at least I think). Next, if I move the increment of `i` inside the condition of the for-loop, `i` will start as `1` instead of `0` and I need to add one more byte `i++<=minute()` and the bytecount will still be the same. But nonetheless, thanks for helping me golf 1 more bytes :)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 235 bytes

```
d=UpdateInterval;e=Dynamic;f=Refresh;g=AbsoluteTime;Grid[Partition[Riffle[e[f[Floor@Mod[g[]/3600+#,24],d->1]]&/@{0,1},With[{t=#},e[f[""<>Array["-"&,If[t==60,60-#,#]]&@Setting@Floor@Mod[g[]/60+#,60],d->1]]]&/@{0,60}],2],Alignment->Left]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python3.5 <s>104</s> <s>127</s> 125 bytes.

<s>from time import*
    while[sleep(9)]:h,m=localtime()[3:5];print("{:02d} {}".format(h,m*'-'),end='\n'*30)</s>

Riffing off Gurupad Mamadapur's answer above.

edit: xnor is right. This isn't a valid answer. - This misses the second line completely.

edit2: Instead, to at least have an answer that works:

<s>from time import*
    while[sleep(9)]:h,m=localtime()[3:5];print("{:02d} {}\n{:02d} {}".format(h,m*'-',h+1,(60-m)*'-'),end='\n'*30)</s>

edit3: Saved two bytes by moving the \n*30 to the format instead of the end='\n'*30

```
from time import*
while[sleep(9)]:h,m=localtime()[3:5];print("{}{:02d} {}\n{:02d} {}".format('\n'*30,h,m*'-',h+1,(60-m)*'-'))
```

Comment: I don't think this does the right thing. The next hour needs to be printed with a dash for each remaining minute to it.

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>192</s> <s>185</s> <s>176</s> <s>172</s> 169 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @nurchi*

```cs
using System;()=>{for(;;){Console.Clear();var t=DateTime.Now;int h=t.Hour,m=t.Minute;Console.Write($"{h:00} {new string('-',m)}\n{++h%24:00} {new string('-',60-m)}");}};
```

Uses C# 6 features which I don't have access to so cannot test it properly yet.

Full version showing how it works and is called including a `Thread.Sleep` so the input can actually be seen. Note that this version shows the use of `Console.Write`s overload to use `String.Format` and doesn't use string interpolation like the golfed version above.

```cs
using System;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action a = () =>
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                Console.Clear();

                var t = DateTime.Now;
                int h = t.Hour,m=t.Minute;

                Console.Write("{0:00} {1}\n{2:00} {3}", h, new string('-', m), ++h % 24, new string('-', 60 - m));

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        };

        a();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your line does not include the `Sleep` (which is included in the full code), so the output will flicker.

Comment: @nurchi the sleep is in the full code to view the output easier, as far as I am aware a smooth clock is not needed

Comment: TheLethalCoder, you are right if the output doesn't flicker too much (it has to be legible). And I just tested it, it barely flickers, but this may depend on the system. My answer below is 176 chars with `Sleep` (but I rely on the `using System.Threading;`. I do like your code though. To further shorten it, replace your `while(1>0){...}` with `for(;;){...}`

Answer (score 1):

### Guile, <s>146</s>, 143 bytes

```
(while(sleep 9)(let*((t(gmtime(current-time)))(h(tm:hour t))(m(tm:min t)))(format #t "~d ~v,,'-t~%~d ~v,,'-t~%" h m(modulo(1+ h)24)(- 60 m))))
```

Shaved off three bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 239 bytes

```
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#define F printf(
void d(n,p){for(;n--;F"%c",p));}int main(){time_t*t;for(;;){d(30,10);time(t);int*m=localtime(t);F"%2d ",m[2]);d(m[1],45);F"\n%2d ",(m[2]+1)%24);d(60-m[1],45);F"\n");sleep(1);}return 0;}
```

Inspired by Seth's and Abel's entries, this will output 0 instead of 24 for the next hour, as required, and will use 30 lines to clear the screen.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 55 bytes

```
TMREAD OUT H,M,
CLS?H,"-"*M?(H+1)MOD 24,"-"*(60-M)EXEC.
```

Explanation:

```
TMREAD OUT HOUR,MINUTE,
CLS
PRINT HOUR,"-"*MINUTE
PRINT (HOUR+1) MOD 24,"-"*(60-MINUTE)
EXEC 0 'runs the code stored in slot 0 (the default)
```

Note: SmileBASIC only has 50 columns of text, so it won't look good...

Answer (score 1):

**C# <strike>181</strike> 176**

```
for(;;){Console.Clear();var t=DateTime.Now;var h=t.Hour;var m=t.Minute;Console.Write("{0,2} {1}\n{2,2} {3}",h,"".PadLeft(m,'-'),++h%24,"".PadLeft(60-m,'-'));Thread.Sleep(100);}
```

This code assumes that the `using System.Threading;` line is included.

Full class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = string.Format("Started the app at: {0}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        //new Timer((o) => { Console.Clear(); var t = DateTime.Now; var h = t.Hour; var m = t.Minute; Console.Write("{0,2} {1}\n{2,2} {3}", h, "".PadLeft(m, '-'), ++h % 24, "".PadLeft(60 - m, '-')); }, null, 0, 60000);

        for (; ; ) { Console.Clear(); var t = DateTime.Now; var h = t.Hour; var m = t.Minute; Console.Write("{0,2} {1}\n{2,2} {3}", h, "".PadLeft(m, '-'), ++h % 24, "".PadLeft(60 - m, '-')); Thread.Sleep(100); }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution has no way of exiting the loop (the original, commented, runs the code on a separate thread), so the `Console.ReadKey` statement is redundant. The only way to exit is to either close the console window or `Ctrl+Break`...

Comment: This is only a code snippet not a method or program, also the `using System.Threading;` needs to be included in the byte count if you are using it. Same with `Using System;`.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 164

```
while 1 {scan [clock f [clock se] -f %T] %d:%d h m
puts "[format %2s $h] [string repe - $m]\n[format %2s [expr ($h+1)%24]] [string repe - [expr 60-$m]]"
after 9999}
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYmh4UlFKeF81TU0)

Comment: This code can be golfed quite a bit. [This](https://goo.gl/zU9n2W
) is only 165 bytes. Also, it doesn't clear the screen (or add 30 newlines) between frames.

Comment: @steenbergh When I execute the code of your link I get errors.

Comment: Oh, now I see what happened. That environment just kept running your original code instead of running my modifications. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 0):

### Bash + Coreutils, 114 bytes

```
while sleep 9; do date +'%k %_M'|{ read h m;printf %02d:%${m}s\n$((h+1)):%$((60-m))s\n" $h|tr " :"  "- "; }; done
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 145 bytes

```javascript
setInterval(c=>[m=(c.clear(),d=new Date()).getMinutes(),60-m].map((m,i)=>c.log(((d.getHours()+i)%24+' ').padStart(3)+'-'.repeat(m))),6e4,console)
```

Ungolfed

```javascript
setInterval(console => {
  console.clear();
  const date = new Date();
  const hour = date.getHours();
  const min = date.getMinutes();
  [
    min,
    60 - min
  ].map((min, i) => console.log(
    ((hour + i) % 24 + ' ').padStart(3) +
    '-'.repeat(min)
  ));
}, 60 * 1000, console);
```